# How can I downgrade My Surface Pro 3 from Windows 10 enterprise to Pro (using the built-in key)

Tags: windows-10

I have a Surface Pro which had Windows 10 enterprise installed but has become deactivated due to no longer being around/associated the organizational infrastructure (KMS?). I want to just downgrade it to the built-in Windows 10 Pro that it came with. How can I do that?

Bonus for doing it without wiping it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this worked for my surface and for another laptop we are working with.

We ran an administrator command prompt, then ran

```
wmic path softwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

This output my original Windows Key.

Then We copied that key into the "Change your product key" option in Settings --> About

**Done**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this downgrade is not
[officially supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/windows-10-upgrade-paths)
by Microsoft.
Yet you might succeed without losing your installed applications
and settings.

You need first to purchase a Windows 10 Pro license
(which you don't need if your Surface came already with Windows Pro
and so is entitled to it), then download the ISO and
create a bootable USB media.

Then you might be able to try the following:

- Open Registry Editor(WIN + R, type regedit, hit Enter)
- Browse to key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
- Change `EditionID` to `Pro` (double click EditionID, change value, click OK). In your case it should at the moment show Enterprise.
- Change `ProductName` to `Windows 10 Pro`. In your case it should at the moment show Windows 10 Enterprise.
- Repeat these two changes for
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`.
- Close the Registry Editor
- Insert the Windows 10 Pro installation media and do an
  [in-place upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
  from the desktop (not booting with Windows 10 Pro install media).
- When asked, enter your valid Windows 10 Pro product key and select what to keep(settings, personal files and apps, only personal files or nothing)

Comment: Surface Pro computers come *with* a full copy of Windows 10 Pro which should already be activated, as clearly stated in the question it was subsequently wiped and installed with a corporate Enterprise edition.  That should not have consumed the Pro licence and he should still be entitled to Pro without paying again.

Comment: @Mokubai: Right - I added this.

Answer (score 1):

For the wipe it and know it is activated for sure option you can download the [Surface Pro recovery media from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/surfacerecoveryimage).

They check your device and serial number so it should activate correctly.

---

*In theory* though the machine has a live digital entitlement for Windows 10 Pro. It should, again *in theory*, be a simple matter of revoking the current licence using `slmgr.vbs /upk` and then letting it reactivate itself online or by running `slui.exe` and attempting to activate it that way.

More details at https://www.groovypost.com/howto/transfer-windows-10-license-new-pc/ in the "uninstalling the licence" section.